# Generate x, y coordinates from input parameters

Tags: excel

I am trying to overlay patient data on top of an optical image. I need to assign X,Y coordinates for each patient file in a bunch of designated boxes in the optical image.

I am currently doing this by hand but I wanted to try and do this automatically by giving Excel the starting coordinate (for the upper left corner pixel of each box), the number of rows and columns for the box as well as the spacing between each pixel. I would need the X and Y coordinates in separate cells.

For instance, for a box with 3 rows, 4 columns, pixel spacing of 20 and starting coordinates of (20,50), the output should look like:

```
X    Y  
20   50  
40   50  
60   50  
80   50  
20   70  
40   70  
60   70  
80   70  
20   90  
40   90  
60   90  
80   90
```

Comment: A screenshot would go a long way towards helping explain what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description maybe:

[image]

Formulas:

`A8`:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=$B$1*$B$2,$B$4+MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,$B$2)*$B$3)
```

`B8`:

```
=IF(A8,$B$5+$B$3*INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/$B$2))
```

Both formulas copied downwards as needed.

Transposed version:

[image]

Formulas:

`B7`:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=$B$1*$B$2,$B$4+MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1,$B$2)*$B$3)
```

`B8`:

```
=IF(B7,$B$5+$B$3*INT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)/$B$2))
```

Both formulas copied sidewards as needed.

Comment: This is perfect Axel! You've saved me a ton of time and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Axel, I was wondering if you could help me alter these formulas a bit. Currently, if you imagine these points being plotted in a 2-D box, they create the X,Y coordinates row by row. Would it be possible to switch this around so coordinates are produced column by column instead? I can provide an example if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried to understand what the formulas do? However, see my supplement.